# How to setup a separate iTunesArtwork file for each Target

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, itunesartwork, ios-targets

I have a xcode project with many *targets* and each *target* has its own *App Icon* and *Launcher Icon*

It's fair to expect that each target has its own *iTunesArtwork* file.

But the problem here is

- The *name of the file can't be changed* and it should be with the name *iTunesArtwork*

  so I can't add a yet another file in the same project for a different target
- The *iTunesArtwork* has  to *be in the root of the project* or else it'd *be ignored*

  I tried creating different folders for different targets and in the respective folder I dragged and dropped the respective *iTunesArtwork* but iTunes Completely ignored it.

***so is there any way while building the app we can move a file from the respective folder to project root*** ?

or

***is there any other way I achieve this through ?***

*Note:*

I am using *jenkins*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using **Folder references** in xcode

Here are the steps

1. I opened my project in the finder then I created a physical folder
   for each target and there I kept the iTunesArtwork and
   iTunesArtwork@2x for respective targets
   (This folders won't be visible in xcode since we're doing it in the finder and as we have physical directory no name collision problem)
2. In xcode I opened my project and I created a *Group* for each *Target*
3. I dragged and dropped the *iTunesArtwork* & *iTunesArtwork2x* in the
   respective Group and I chose the respective target in Target list
   and I chose *Folder references*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create new image.xcess asset and select target- build settings find xassets replace that neme for your inageassets name for that  target